# Checkbox check add price

Tags: android, android-studio, checkbox

I am trying to do an android application that allow user to select item and the application able to calculate the total cost.

May I know how to add the amount into a total value when a check box is checked and how to reduce the amount when it is unchecked? Tq

```
checkBoxListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Topping = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_TopAns);
            Topping.setText(" ");

            if(ChkCheese.isChecked()){
                Topping.setText(Topping.getText().toString() + ChkCheese.getText().toString());
                ToppingPrice += 2.5;
                TotalPrice = SizePrice + CrustPrice + ToppingPrice;
                Price.setText("RM" + TotalPrice );
            }

            if(ChkMushroom.isChecked()){
                Topping.setText(Topping.getText().toString() + "," + ChkMushroom.getText().toString());

                ToppingPrice += 1;
                TotalPrice = SizePrice + CrustPrice + ToppingPrice;
                Price.setText("RM" + TotalPrice );
            }

            if(ChkChicken.isChecked()){
                Topping.setText(Topping.getText().toString() + "," + ChkChicken.getText().toString());
                ToppingPrice += 2;
                TotalPrice = SizePrice + CrustPrice + ToppingPrice;
                Price.setText("RM" + TotalPrice );
            }
            if(ChkBeef.isChecked()){
                Topping.setText(Topping.getText().toString() + "," + ChkBeef.getText().toString());
                ToppingPrice += 4;
                TotalPrice = SizePrice + CrustPrice + ToppingPrice;
                Price.setText("RM" + TotalPrice );
            }
            if(ChkPepperoni.isChecked()){
                Topping.setText(Topping.getText().toString() + "," + ChkPepperoni.getText().toString());
                ToppingPrice +=3.5;

                TotalPrice = SizePrice + CrustPrice + ToppingPrice;
                Price.setText("RM" + TotalPrice );
            }
            if(ChkOlive.isChecked()){
                Topping.setText(Topping.getText().toString() + "," + ChkOlive.getText().toString());
                ToppingPrice += 2;
                TotalPrice = SizePrice + CrustPrice + ToppingPrice;
                Price.setText("RM" + TotalPrice );
            }
            if(ChkPineapple.isChecked()){
                Topping.setText(Topping.getText().toString() + "," + ChkPineapple.getText().toString());
                ToppingPrice += 1;
                TotalPrice = SizePrice + CrustPrice + ToppingPrice;
                Price.setText("RM" + TotalPrice );
            }


        }
    } ;
    ChkCheese.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
    ChkMushroom.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
    ChkBeef.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
    ChkPineapple.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
    ChkOlive.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
    ChkPepperoni.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
    ChkChicken.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
```

Comment: Please add the code you are trying to use

Comment: if you share your code then i will help , i will not write the whole code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the price of each item inside each checkboxes tag and retrieve it from there.  
Also you need to subtract the price if the checkbox is unchecked and remove it from the textview.  
Something like this, although I can't test this code:

```
ChkCheese.setTag("2.5");
ChkMushroom.setTag("1.0");
ChkBeef.setTag("4.0");
ChkPineapple.setTag("1.0");
ChkOlive.setTag("2.0");
ChkPepperoni.setTag("3.5");
ChkChicken.setTag("2.0");

checkBoxListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Topping = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_TopAns);
        Topping.setText("");

        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;

        double itemPrice = Double.parseDouble(cb.getTag().toString());

        String newText = Topping.getText().toString();
        if (!cb.isChecked()) {
            itemPrice *= -1.0;
            newText = newText.replace(cb.getText().toString(), "").replace(",,", ",");
            if (newText.indexOf(",") == 0 && newText.length() > 1) newText = newText.substring(1);
            Topping.setText(Topping.getText().toString() + "," + cb.getText().toString());
        } else {
            Topping.setText(newText + "," + cb.getText().toString());
        }

        ToppingPrice += itemPrice;
        TotalPrice = SizePrice + CrustPrice + ToppingPrice;
        Price.setText("RM" + TotalPrice );
    }
} ;
ChkCheese.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
ChkMushroom.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
ChkBeef.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
ChkPineapple.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
ChkOlive.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
ChkPepperoni.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
ChkChicken.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
//global var
int total = 0;
(...)
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
{
    Object tag = buttonView.getTag();
    //This tag can be the numeric value you want, can be setted on xml or programatically
    if ( isChecked )
    {
         total += (int)tag;
    }
    else
    {
         total -= (int)tag;
    }

}
```